# JS: When is Function.prototype.apply() or call() necessary to refer to this

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pass-by-reference, middleware

I am learning JS. I was working with Mongoose and I wanted do pass a function and parameter(s) to a callback, but I have to use call() instead.

```
// Car is a model. Using Express in Node.js
express.Router().route('/')
    .get((req,res,next)=>{
        print(res,next,Cars.find)
    })

const print = async(res,next,func,param1={})=>{
    try {
        const cars = await func.call(Cars,param1)
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(cars);
    } catch (err)
        next(err);
}
```

It does not work for me when I simply do func(param1) inside print(...), which returns this error.

```
MongooseError: `Model.find()` cannot run without a model as `this`.
Make sure you are calling `MyModel.find()` where `MyModel` is a Mongoose model.
```

Could you please explain why that is and when I need to use apply()/call() to pass in this? In this context of Mongoose and in general?

Also I'm a bit confused on next() and next(err). Documentation says it's just so the program can "skip" the error in some sense and I can visibly see that. But is it like a callback function that we can modify or it's something built in?

EDIT: Im looking at [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) and is it because somehow the object is not passed into `print()`?

Comment: That won't work. `func_param1 = {}` isn't iterable

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh I see I used call() instead of apply() in my dev code. But the syntax of apply() or call() is not what I'm asking about. I changed it to call(). Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use `call` here - now your `print` function works only for the `Cars` model. Instead, use the simple `await func();`, but pass `Cars.find.bind(Cars, {})` or `() => Cars.find({})` as the callback.

Comment: thanks @Bergi. Because for different http requests I'll be using different methods, so I'll call `Cars.find()` in the parent function `get()` instead. Much easier to debug that way. But this is definitely good to know as a tool in my toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In js, `this` [is determined at run time](https://javascript.info/object-methods#this-is-not-bound) and refers to what runs the method. If the method is defined by or is called in an arrow function then `this` bubbles up to the parent function. In this case `this` would have been `get()` had I not used `call()`. So I was correct in a sense that the parent object `Cars` was not passed along with `Cars.find()`.